# Phaser, delete outOfBounds sprite

Tags: javascript, sprite, phaser-framework

I've find some code example of garbageCollector for deleting sprites that out of screen, but it's working only in older version of Phaser.
How can I rebuild this code from v1.1.5 to v2.0.4?
Error code:

```
Phaser v2.0.3 - WebGL - WebAudio     http://phaser.io    в™Ґв™Ґв™Ґ  phaser.min.js:8
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null (index):34
    add_cloud (index):34
    b.Timer.update phaser.min.js:12
    b.Time.update phaser.min.js:12
    b.Game.update phaser.min.js:8
    b.RequestAnimationFrame.updateRAF phaser.min.js:11
    window.requestAnimationFrame.forceSetTimeOut._onLoop phaser.min.js:11
```

Code that work on older version (v1.1.5):

```
<script>
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 480, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
    var clouds;
    var cloud_dummy;

    function preload() {
        game.load.image('mario_cloud', 'mario_cloud.png');
    }

    function create() {
        clouds = game.add.group();
        clouds.enableBody = true;
        clouds.createMultiple( 6, 'mario_cloud');

        timer_shit = game.time.events.loop(1500, add_cloud, this);
    }
    function update() {

    }
    function add_cloud() {
        cloud_dummy = clouds.getFirstDead();
        cloud_dummy.reset(800, 100);
        cloud_dummy.body.velocity.x -= 150;
        cloud_dummy.body.immovable = true;
        cloud_dummy.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Live demo: http://koryato.yomu.ru/tests/

Comment: I find an solution.
Just add string cloud_dummy.checkWorldBounds = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error code is telling you that there is no child in the group "clouds" with the property "alive" = false.

This is why in this line.

```
cloud_dummy.reset(800, 100);
```

you have a 'null'.

What can be the reason is first the performance of your game is more bad then before, so the clouds in this example are all at the same time inside the game canvas.

Because what this line is doing

```
cloud_dummy.outOfBoundsKill = true;
```

is that the property "alive" is set to false when the item leaves the visible part of the game.

What you can try to do is just add more childs in the group like so

```
clouds.createMultiple( 50, 'mario_cloud');
```

But i can remember i had a similar problem where i was forced to set initially the property "alive" to true.

check this [link](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Group.html#forEach) for how to change each child of a group..

you could do something like this after you initially create the group

```
forEach(function(child){
child.alive = true;
}, this, false)
```

Comment: I've tried to play with parametrs. That's haven't help.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for your idea. I find broken part of this program.
When I create a child of group, I haven't set parameter checkWorldBounds to true. So program won't check sprite position on screen.
And function like that in update dose similar things.
clouds.forEach(function(cloud){
if(!cloud.inWorld) cloud.alive = false; //'Kill' sprites that outOfBounds
}, this, false)